# get linked data from user table in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I have this linkUser Table

> ```
> id |  User Id |   LinkedUser ID
> ```

```
1        4            6
2        6            4
3        1            6
4        6            1
5        1            2
6        6            3
7        3            6
```

and then there is user table

```
id  |  name  
1      user 1
2      user 2
3      user 3
..
..
```

I want to get all user detail where current user id is linked to other user id. Like if current logged in user id is `6` then it should return data `4,1,3` data from user table

I'm trying like this

```
DB::table('linked')->where('user_id', $loggedUserId)->get();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return all the user details where current logged-in user id is linked to other user id :

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('linkUser', 'users.id', '=', 'linkUser.user_id')
    ->where('linkUser.linked_user_id', $loggedUserId)
    ->select('users.*')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but this is giving me results if value is in one row only but according to my logic there should be two entries for linking like `User ID` should be `4` and linked `user id is 6` and `linked User id should be 4` and and `User ID` should be `6`

Comment: i have tried this query but it is returning `2,3,4` user record but is should return `2,4` record i have added screenshot also in the above question can you pls check

Comment: Check my answer. Just leave a comment if there are still any issues. I have to break my fast now, and I will be back later.

Comment: tried but still it is returning id 3 but logged in user id is 1, 3 should not be returned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252834/discussion-between-wahyu-kristianto-and-user3653474).

Answer (score 0):

> May be this will help, you can try this.

```
$loggedUserId = 6; // Make sure you getting "6"

DB::table('user u')
->leftjoin('linked l', 'l.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
->where('u.user_id', $loggedUserId)
->select('u.*')
->get();
```